# ratio of 2 chi square to get f-distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, chi-squared-distribution, f-distribution

How can I use two chi square functions to make a f function?  I only see invchisquare functions in some languages when I need to use an inv f-dist to get the exact binomial CI.  So, looking to figure out how (in excel for example) to create the f.inv from the chisq.inv

Comment: You don't do this, because the relationship involves integration.  If you're using Excel, see the `F.DIST` family of functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $X,Y \sim_{ind} \chi^2$ with degrees of freedom $p-1$ and $n-p-1$ respectively, then the ratio

$$\dfrac{X/(p-1)}{Y/(n-p-1)} \sim F_{p-1, n-p-1}$$

The Clopper-Pearson method for exact binomial confidence intervals uses the following interval estimates expressed in terms of F-critical values:

$$ \left[\left(1 + \dfrac{n-x+1}{x F_{\alpha/2, 2x, 2(n-x+1))}}\right)^{-1}, \left(1 + \dfrac{n-x}{(x+1) F_{1-\alpha/2, 2(x+1), 2(n-x))}}\right)^{-1}\right]$$

If the denominator degrees of freedom is large, then most algorithms use invert the chi-square with numerator degrees of freedom since the distributions are nearly the same. Otherwise, a beta-approximation is used. If your software doesn't have an F quantile function, it probably doesn't have a beta-one either. Perhaps the Chi-square approximation will work in most cases you are dealing with.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685469?origin=crossref

Comment: I believe the OP may be referring to formulas for the Binomial CDF, which can be expressed in terms of the CDFs of related $F$ distributions.  This is because they are both given by [incomplete Beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function).  This is not an approximation.

Comment: @AdamO are you sure you have that right?  Note that $X/(X+Y)$ must lay between $0$ and $1$, while an $F$ is on $(0,\infty)$. Note also that if $X$ and $Y$ are chi-squared with different d.f. they can't be "identically distributed" (per your "i.i.d.")

Comment: @Glen_b haste makes waste, please see revision. This is right, right?

Comment: @whuber I tried to follow OP's train of thought a bit better in light of your comment. Is the edit helpful?

Comment: @AdamO The things I was objecting to before look correct now (I didn't check further, time is pressing right now). The X/(X+Y) you had before would be beta-distributed.